# Функция очистки экрана в Си без подключения дополнительных библиотек

Tags: c, printf

Собственно нашел такой способ с помощью команды `printf ("\033[0d\033[2J");`, теперь пытаюсь понять запись внутри функции. Если вы знаете другой способ, или понимаете что обозначает запись `\033[0d\033[2J` жду вашей помощи)

Comment: [отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI) и далее по ссылкам.

Comment: С *не знает*, что такое *экран*... Самый переносимый способ — сделать достаточно много выводов `\n` :), правда, курсор останется внизу. Ваш способ через ANSI последовательности тоже работает не всегда и не везде...

Comment: ваши команды обрабатывает программа консоли. А версий консолей великое множество. Чтобы ответить важно знать какая у вас. например так : `> echo $0
/bin/bash`

Comment: printf ("\f"); - очистка экрана консоли, должно работать везде и всегда, это вреде как стандарт.